# So this question title was edited with no seeming or expressed reason?

Tags: discussion

[The question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382115/eating-people-is-wrong-but-its-wrong-to-eat-people-why)  was originally titled

> Why "Using X is better" but "It's better to use X"?

The first title edit incorporated  two of four example questions expressed by the OP in their actual question,  namely

> Why "Using a keyboard is better" but "It's better to use a keyboard"?

I found this edit to be helpful; and again  it contains  two  of four sentences actually used by the OP in the question body.  But later the same user (not the OP)  edited the title to

> "Eating people is wrong" but "It's wrong to eat people" - Why?

which I don't see a good reason for, since any import of such a title may be lost on the OP, and others,  but mainly because it loses the explicit "teaching moment" of using two sentences provided by the OP in exchange for one of entire different substance...

Comment: All three titles are absolutely terrible! Titles need to ask proper questions, not just "WHY???"

Comment: @curiousdannii - Titles here do not have to be in the form of a question, in the same way titles anywhere don't have to be in the form of a sentence. However, i agree that *Why "A" but "B"?* is bad -- should perhaps be *"A" v "B"*.

Comment: None of the edits tried to address the form of the title, they only changed the text in the quotes. It seems like the original editor was deliberately trying to be provocative, replacing an innocuous phrase about keyboards with ones about cannibalism. Your undoing of these edits seems very appropriate.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don’t see what the problem is here. The _proper question_ would be “Why are infinitival subjects almost always extrapositioned in copular constructions with non-infinitival predicates to the subject when gerundial subjects are not?”, but I hope we can agree that that is far worse than any of the three titles quoted here. Firstly, it’s much too long for a title; secondly, and just as importantly, the vast majority of people who will know exactly what the original title refers to will have no idea what the ‘proper’ question is about.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The best title would probably be something like "Why do we usually say "It's wrong to eat people" rather than "To eat people is wrong"?" If the title is phrased like that then it asks a proper question, and one whose assumption is ripe to be challenged on the basis of corpus data.